# File Permissions Vary from Git Bash to Cygwin Command Line

Tags: git, cygwin, git-bash

I am on a Windows 8 machine. I use Git Bash when doing source control. I use Cygwin to ssh into my server.

I have a sensitive file (private key in fact), which I want to have `rwx-rwx----` permissions.

When running `ls -l` from the Cygwin command line, the permissions for this particular file are `rwx-rwx----`. This is exactly what I want, good.

However, when I run `ls -l` from Git Bash, it says the permissions are `rw--r---r--`. This is not what I want. I even tried doing a `chmod` from Git Bash on this file, and it didn't change anything.

I am assuming the permissions are just incorrect when viewing them from Git Bash. The file just doesn't have the permissions Git Bash thinks it has. However, I am worried that Git Bash could be correct. If this is the case, this is bad.

Is Git Bash just wrong? Or what? I am concerned because I don't want this file to be world readable.

In the event that Git Bash is simply displaying the permissions wrong, why is that? I know it isn't necessarily a big deal, but I am curious as to why it would distort this files permissions.

Comment: When you say `git bash` is this a Cygwin version of git, or a windows version?

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that rather than `rwx-rwx----`, all you really need is
`rwx` for current user. If that be the case, you can run

```
chmod a+x infile
```

where `a` makes it apply to all users.

[chmod Man Page](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)